# LOOP on files ! PARSE FILES and GROUP them by IDENTIFIER?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, parsing

I would like to :

1. Read the list of * .txt files from the directory
2. For all the .txt files in my folder, I would like to use the information contained in all the rows id=NAME, part of the fifth column in all the *.txt files (e.g., Hox.txt and zinc.txt below)
3. Determine which family the given file belongs to (e.g cram-2) using a separate lookup table linking id values to a Family value (e.g., Lookup Table below)
4. Combine/concatenate all the files with the same family (e.g HOX.txt and zinc.txt) into one .txt file.
5. Save the linked file with the name of the column Family (e.g cram-2.txt).

**!! REMINDER !!
!! R WILL HAVE TO WORK ON A LOT AND HEAVY .txt FILES - NEED OF A TEMPORARY DIRECTORY? !!**

*Example:*

The HOX.txt file rows :

```
ma  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
se  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
to  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
pa  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
```

The zinc.txt file rows :

```
ma  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
se  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
to  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
pa  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
```

The lookup table :

```
Name                        Family
HOX                         cram-2
zinc                        cram-2
fire                        sf.xr
fire                        ra.XS-2
...continues...
```

*The final output I search to obtain :*

a) File name = cram-2.txt

b) Concatenate HOX.txt and zinc.txt because both are from Family cram-2!

```
ma  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
se  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
to  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
pa  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
ma  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
se  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
to  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
pa  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
```

*Code working on few  files.bed only.*
*I tried using tempfile() and tempdir() but still didn't worked.*

```
dfNameFamily = tibble(
  Name = as.character(df$Name),  
  Family = as.character(df$Family)

dir = "~/textfiles"

TxtFile = function(dir) dir_ls(dir, regexp = "\\.txt$")

readTxt = function(FileName){
  lines = character()
  if(file_exists(FileName)){
    con = file(FileName, open = "r")
    lines = readLines(con)
    close(con)
  }
  lines
}

GetName = function(l) str_match(l, ";id=(.+);seq")[1,2]

SaveFile = function(l, name, dir){
  con = file(paste0(dir, "/" , name))
  writeLines(unlist(l$lines), con)
  close(con)
}

tibble(FileName = TxtFile(dir)) %>%  
  mutate(
    lines = map(FileName, readTxt),  
    Name = map_chr(lines, GetName)) %>%  
  left_join(dfNameFamily, by="Name") %>%  
  group_by(Family) %>%  
  group_walk(SaveFile, dir)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site for hiring someone to write code for you. You need to show what you have done so far and people will be glad to find answers and solve exact problems met by you. You can read here about how to provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

Gather the files to be processed in the `bedDir` directory. Create a directory `bedOut` for the output files. It's best to keep this in one RStudio project where you create these directories.

Extend the `Names` and `Families` vectors accordingly according to your needs.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)
library(utils)

Names = c("HOX", "zinc", "fire", "fire2")
Families = c("cram-2", "cram-2", "sf.xr", "ra.XS-2")
GetName = function(l) str_match(l, "id=(.+);seq")[1,2]
GetFamily = function(l) Families[which(Names==GetName(l))]

BedFile = function(dir) dir_ls(dir, regexp = "\\.bed$")

info = function(txt, start_time, end_time){
  tdif = end_time - start_time
  tunit = " ms"
  if(tdif>=1000){
    tdif = tdif/1000
    tunit = " s"
  }
  cat(paste0("Read ", txt," (", round(tdif,2),tunit,")\n"))
}

time_ms = function() as.numeric(as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000, digits=15)

pbTitle = function(path, files, i){
  paste("[", round(i/length(files)*100, 0),"%]",
        "files have been read from the", path, "directory.",
        "The file being read:", files[i])}

bedDir = "bedDir"
bedOut = "bedOut"
files = BedFile(bedDir)
if(length(files)>0){
  start_time = time_ms()
  pb = winProgressBar(max = length(files), width = 500)
  on.exit(close(pb), add = TRUE)

  for(i in 1:length(files)){
    setWinProgressBar(pb, i-1, pbTitle(bedDir, files, i-1))
    lines = fread(text = files[i], sep = "|", header=FALSE)
    Name = GetName(lines[1])
    Family = GetFamily(lines[1])
    fileName = paste0(bedOut, "/", Family, ".bad")
    fwrite(lines, fileName, append = file_exists(fileName))
  }

  close(pb)
  info(paste(length(files), "files"), start_time, time_ms())
}
```

P.S.
I recommend that you note that I used the fastest known functions for reading and writing `fread` and `fwrite` text files from the `data.table` package here.

Let me know if that's it and how fast it works.

Comment: Worked on 137 Gbts in less than 10 minutes. This is astonishingly thank you so much! @MarekFiolka

Comment: The most important thing is to know the problem well. As you already know him, you can look for the optimal solution for him. Your original description of the problem was somewhat confusing and incomplete. While writing the first version of program, I was rather guessing what you expect. Knowing your problem fully, I was able to optimize it. Hope you learned something by the way (for sure how `txtProgressBar` works). Finally, check out my other answers. Perhaps one of them will be equally informative for you and you will want to click "This answer is useful". I'll be glad.

Comment: Yes it was useful, took a bit to understand each part of the code though. Sure, I ll go through your other inputs and informative answers. Best, and thank you again! @MarekFiolka